Can dereferencing the pointer p in the same expression as its being incremented lead to undefined behavior?
In chapter 8.6.1 of Bjarne Stroustrups principle and practice using C++ he writes:

The order of evaluation of sub-expressions is governed by rules
designed to please an optimizer rather than to make life simple for
the programmer. That’s unfortunate, but you should avoid complicated
expressions anyway, and there is a simple rule that can keep you out
of trouble: if you change the value of a variable in an expression,
don’t read or write it twice in that same expression. For example:
v[i] = ++i;                                       // don’t: undefined order of evaluation
v[++i] = i;                                       // don’t: undefined order of evaluation
int x = ++i + ++i;                           // don’t: undefined order of evaluation
cout << ++i << ' ' << i << '\n';      // don’t: undefined order of evaluation
f(++i,++i);                                    // don’t: undefined order of evaluation

Unfortunately, not all compilers warn if you write such bad code; it’s
bad because you can’t rely on the results being the same if you move
your code to another computer, use a different compiler, or use a
different optimizer setting. Compilers really differ for such code;
just don’t do it.

I know its a very long quote to paste, but I wanted to include the full context of what he wrote. Some time after reading this I found the following code online for writing out the byte representation of objects:
template <typename T>
void print_bytes(const T& input, std::ostream& os = std::cout)
{
    const uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&input); 
    os << std::hex << std::showbase;
    os << "[";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i)
    {
        os << std::setw(5) << static_cast<int>(*(p++)) << " ";
    }
    os << "]" << std::endl;
    os << std::dec << std::noshowbase;
}

The pointer p is incremented in the same expression as its dereferenced and printed out. Does this mean the line: os << std::setw(5) << static_cast<int>(*(p++)) << " "; could lead to different behavior depending on compiler, platform etc.?

no, only one of the operations mutates so only one thing can happen.

@anatolyg from the context I think the OP means p (i.e. this is the sense of the relevant pointer in the question). But the OP should clarify.

The difference between *p++ and the other examples is that Stroustrup's examples the variable occurs more than once.  Which is a critical piece of the puzzle (it's what the "...twice..." refers to).

@Eljay this makes more sense now. Originally I thought the quote mentioning "don’t read or write it twice ..." to be somewhat confusing being applied to this case (although it is clearly valid).

In chapter 8.6.1 of Bjarne Stroustrups principle and practice using C++ Which edition? v[i] = ++i; v[++i] = i; are defined in the actual C++ (since C++17?)

@273K second edition which covers c++11 and c++14

@273K could you mention the eval order for assignment please?

@Red.Wave The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.

The rule is meant to be understood pretty literally.

if you change the value of a variable in an expression, don’t read or write it twice in that same expression

Here "change" is either "write" or "read, then write". Which in the context of the rule is the same.
Let me enumerate the possibilities:

1 * read + 2 * write = trouble
2 * read + 1 * write = trouble
2 * write = trouble
2 * read = OK
1 * read + 1 * write = OK
1 * read = OK
1 * write = OK

Here "trouble" means "depending on your code, it can be OK or undefined behavior" and OK means "your code is probably good — if it's bad, it's not because of unsequenced read/write conflicts".
Your code falls in the "one read, one write" category, so it's good. It's in fact idiomatic code — it's supposed to be so clear that parentheses are usually omitted in that context. That is, *p++ is widely understood as "read from pointer p, then advance it".
The rules for sequencing reads and writes have been changed several times in subtle ways. You probably don't want to understand these! If you use the rule of "don't access twice", you don't need to understand these finer parts of the C++ specification.

Unfortunately that doesn't capture pre-increment well, e.g. auto q = ++p;. There is a read clearly after the write, but I guess the idea is not to disallow all pre-increment/decrement. And "1 * read + 1 * write" generally is not fine if there is no obvious ordering involved, e.g. q - (q=0).

Regarding auto q = ++p — I don't see any problem. Regarding q - (q=0) — it should be viewed as two reads, once you read q and then you read q=0. I guess it depends on your intuition on what a "read" is.

1 * read + 1 * write = OK: i + ++i is not ok, or is that 2 reads?

@anatolyg Oops, I meant something like (q, q=0) instead of q - (q=0), where there is only one read and one write. For the the pre-increment case I am saying that it has "write, then read" or even "read, then write, then read" instead of "read, then write"

Yes, the rule now doesn't look quite intuitive to me. It only works if you say that ++ is always 1 read and 1 write (not 2 reads). Still better than nothing. Regarding the example with the comma operator — it looks like the comma makes the ordering well-defined, but the rule still says that you are not supposed to use such complicated expressions. You don't even need a separate rule for "don't use comma operator" ;)

@273K I assume lvalue-to-rvalue conversion = read; and ++ = read and write. So i + ++i is 2 reads and write — no good. It's not immediately obvious what a "read" or a "write" is, so I am not sure about the usefulness of all this.

"Here "change" is either "write" or "read, then write"...." Shouldn't it be only "write" but not read?

Maybe, but it doesn't matter. If you do the logic assuming any definition of "change", you will get the same results.

In *(p++), the * operator is not applied to the object p.
The result of a post-increment on a scalar type is a prvalue that holds the original value of the incremented object, not a lvalue referring to the operand's object (as in pre-increment). You apply * to that prvalue.
Now, of course, in order to obtain that value there is a read on p. And there is also a write on p to perform the increment. If you read the quoted rule too strictly, then this means you perform two accesses which you shouldn't if there is a modification involved.
However, if you take the rule that strictly, then you can never perform any increment at all. Every increment requires a read and a write at the same time. Obviously this is not what the author meant. The read/write combination in an increment should be counted as one operation for the purpose of the rule, including any read applied to the result of a pre-increment/decrement as well. The idea is to look at distinct operands in the expression that refer to the same object.
Also, not all cases where the rule is violated are automatically undefined behavior. It is meant to make it easier by forbidding more than UB would, without having to remember and verify the more complex actual order-of-evaluation rules.
In this case there is no UB in the *(p++) subexpression. The value computation of a post-increment on a scalar type is sequenced before the side effect of the increment. Therefore, since no value computation or other side effect on p is unsequenced with the side effect of the increment on p, there is no UB.
*(p++) is a very common pattern to iterate over an array via pointer. I do not think that it is useful to try to avoid it.

A minor issue with the code snippet though: Using uint8_t for the purpose of iterating over the object representation of an object is not a good idea in general. It makes the assumption that uint8_t is an alias for unsigned char. And while that is probably the case on all relevant implementations, it is not guaranteed by the standard.
If uint8_t is not unsigned char, then the code snippet has undefined behavior for an aliasing violation when attempting to access the underlying bytes of an object (other than of type uint8_t or its signed variant) through uint8_t. Only unsigned char (and maybe char and std::byte) is permitted to be used to access underlying bytes of an object. (Although that whole concept is currently a bit underspecified in the standard anyway.)

Thank you for the answer. The original code actually used unsigned char. But in a post I created yesterday @Christian Stieber said: "Note that I generally prefer using uint8_t when dealing with "bytes", but since your code used unsigned char, I stuck with that. If at all possible, I use char only when dealing with "text" characters" but I might have misunderstood what he meant.

@user3612 I generally agree that uint8_t is clearer for working with bytes. It says clearly in the name that it is an unsigned 8bit type, while unsigned char can potentially be larger than that (in which case uint8_t would not exist) and it goes well with all the other uintXX_t aliases. However, for this particular purposes there is technically a different meaning between uint8_t and unsigned char in the abstract. Only the latter is guaranteed to be usable when accessing bytes of an object that itself is not an uint8_t (or signed variant of it).

@user3612 That said though, I am not aware of any C++ implementation implementation where uint8_t is not unsigned char and I know that it is commonly used for this purpose regardless. I also often see the assumption that uint8_t is unsigned char used in other places, e.g. when calling a function requiring a unsigned char* with a uint8_t*. I am just not a big fan of doing it that way.

@user17732522 std::byte meant to be too, thus it surprised me at first that uint8_t isn't. well, technically uint8-T is guaranteed 8 bits. char and byte are the smallest adressable amount of storage, which might be not equal to uint8_t.

@Swift-FridayPie I have added std::byte in my answer, although the only paper I am aware of that intended to actually make reading object representations byte-by-byte well-defined (currently underspecified) does permit only unsigned char for that purpose. It is a bit distinct from the aliasing issue. uint8_t never had any special meaning in the sense of "bytes of memory", smallest addressable amount of memory, or such. It is simply an integer type that can hold 8bit wide numbers. Nothing special to all the other uintXX_t.

In C++17 there was If a complete object is created (8.5.2.4) in storage associated with another object e of type “array of N unsigned char” or of type “array of N std::byte” (21.2.1), that array provides storage for the created object... which like can be inverted. IT's one byte to one byte  (so there is no smaller array), even one can argu that std::byte and std::byte[1] are different types. I do not argue point about uint8_t, just these with non-lawyer mind are usually blindsided by that.

@Swift-FridayPie That's technically still a separate issue and in that line there is no mention of char, which however has the aliasing exception as well. The actual reinterpret_cast that's intended to return a pointer into the object representation is currently not specified to actually do that, so it is a bit pointless to try to figure out which types exactly are allowed. However, if it isn't one of the types permitting aliasing, then it is surely not supposed to work. There was this attempt to make it defined, which seems stalled.

@user17732522 yeah, that's 25-year-long crusade. I think, at best we'll have implementation-defined behaviour, because object can contain  padding and bytes skipped by alignment (and other representation details)

The actual rule is that having two unsequenced writes to the same memory location, or one read from a memory location and one write to that same memory location that are unsequenced, is undefined behaviour.
But *(p++) doesn't violate this rule. It does 3 things:

Read p
Write to p 1 plus the value read by #1
Dereference the value of p that was read by #1

There is only one read and one write involving the memory location where p is stored. #1 does the read, #2 does the write. #3 doesn't access the memory location again; it just uses the value that was already read in #1.
Because #3 doesn't access the memory location where p is stored, it doesn't matter whether it happens before or after #2, or even at the same time. (The semantics of the language guarantee that the pointer value dereferenced in #3 will be the value prior to incrementation in all cases.)
The important thing is the sequencing of #1 and #2. If they were unsequenced relative to each other, the behaviour would be undefined. But, obviously, you have to read a scalar value first before you can write a value that depends on that value. And indeed, according to the standard, #1 is sequenced before #2. So no UB.
